# why queryselector returns the name of the selector and not the content

Tags: javascript, dom, queryselector

I am currently following an online class and I can't understand why I don't have the same thing as the teach in my console.

I have an h1 in my HTML, followed by this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(document.querySelector('h1'));
</script>
```

I am supposed to get the content of the h1 in my console but it returns me the selector title. I have not found something that could help me in @.. (and just to be sure I tried it on several browsers).

EDIT :
I am supposed to get this:

[image: An image showing the tag I'm Mr. JavaScript in the browser console]

And i get this:

[image: An image showing an expandable element in the browser console]

FINAL EDIT :
Thank you everyone, I believe this is only a matter of browser (didn't work on Chrome and Firefox but ok on Edge).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/91wJtW3 — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: What browser are you using when you took the screenshot? (and what browser is your teacher using?)

Comment: Hahaha ok this is weird, thank you I will continue the course as if nothing happened, maybe this won't be so important

Comment: @NickParsons I used Chrome, Firefox aaannnd I just tested it on Edge and it works. Simple as this, thank you !!!!

Comment: @July Nice, I get your teacher's output in Chrome, but when I try in Firefox [I get your output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwDyW.png) - console's can show objects/html elements in different ways from browser to browser, but it won't change how your code functions

Comment: Okay thw again, this is a good advice for a newbie like me. Never though I would use Edge again...

Comment: See! You're a proper developer already.

Comment: @Andy ahah lol thanks ;)

Answer (score -1):

you just need to add the .innerHTML at the end.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes that works and gets me the text but the teacher has <h1>text</h1> in his console and that's what I would like to reproduce. But maybe this is absolutely not important for keeping up with JS...